# How to change a user's password programatically

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to create a totally different profile page (not the one provided by Wordpress), since the layout and feel of the default profile page is too "Wordpress" for the users. Now I am successful in being able to present a page that can modify user meta data like firstname, lastname, city, zip code, etc.

Now what stumped me is changing the password of the user. Is there any built-in wordpress function, say change_user_password($user_id, $new_password)? I'm surprised that I can't look for anything that does this.

Worse comes to worst I'm doing an `UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = md5($new_password) WHERE ID = $user_id`, but I would be really amazed if there is no function for this one.

Comment: `md5` for passwords in WordPress is deprecated (but still backwards compatible - next time user logins password will be re-hashed and re-saved). It is better to go through API so that current and more complex hashing scheme is used.

Comment: Yeah, I that's my guess as well. The passwords stored in the database does not match an MD5 with the incoming password. So yeah, it is indeed rehashed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
```

See [reference](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_set_password/) for details.

Comment: I up voted this essentially because this results in single sql query. Excellent, if the password is, all that you want to update. `wp_update_user` results in about 14 queries running.

Answer (score 17):

A simple `wp_update_user(array('ID' => $userid, 'user_pass' => 'myNeWpaSSword'))` will do everything for you - [`wp_update_user()` (Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user).

On a sidenote: are you aware of the [Theme My Login (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)? It can provide you with a front-end side profile page.