# How to change user password with wp-cli?

Tags: password, wp-cli

[wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) is great. But it's not clear how I can quickly change a user password with it.

[How to change a user's password programatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/how-to-change-a-users-password-programatically) can probably help to figure this out.

Although `wp user update username --field=password` is not gonna cut it, apparently `md5` is deprecated so it should go through [`wp_set_password`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_set_password/).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
wp user update USERNAME --user_pass="PASSWORD"
```

(Found it [here](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1809).)

Comment: Hmmm, that's the example used on the [`wp user update`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/user/update/) page in the wp-cli docs.

Comment: Security Pointer: Add a space in front of this command to make sure you're not including a plaintext password in your bash `history`.

Answer (score 21):

first check the user name:

```
wp user list
```

then change password without leaving traces in history

```
wp user update admin --prompt=user_pass
```

Comment: Leaving a space before the command will ensure it is not added to the bash `history` if someone requires something non-interactive.

Answer (score 3):

Just to append one minor thing; sometimes the password may start with the = character. I prefer using this notation, just because of that.

```
wp user update USERNAME --user_pass="PASSWORD"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sudo definitely changes the path, so I have tried using --allow-root without sudo and the commands work