# Can I create (or update) user password with WP-CLI by hash?

Tags: wp-cli

I want to make a user-create snippet, but it must not includes plain password.

```
   $ wp user create username username@example.com --role=administrator --user_pass=password
```

So can I create (or update) user password by hashed value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not "one command" in Wordpress CLI that does the job: https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2270

However using other commands, you can overide the user password directly in the database using the following:

```
USER_ID=$(wp user list --login="$USR_LOGIN" --format=ids)
wp db query "UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass='$HASHED_PASS' WHERE ID = $USER_ID;"
```

First line is optional if you already know the user ID.

To hash a password, use the following:

```
wp eval "echo wp_hash_password('$CLEAR_PASSWORD');"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
wp user update USERNAME --user_pass=PASSWORD
```

Found it [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193085)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/121705)

Comment: @cjbj The link was simply stating where I got the answer from... It has nothing to do with the actual answer

Comment: Is it plain text password, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I found this while looking for a similar solution. Best solution (unless you alter the DB directly) seems to be the --prompt argument.
You can pass the new password over stdin with

```
wp user update <USER> --prompt=user_pass
```

This avoids having the PW show up in your history/process list.